# Eigenvalues of an infinite matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, infinity

I have matrix elements

$$
H_{mn} = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(m-n)^2} & m \neq n \\
0 & m=n
\end{cases}$$

If the indices extend to infinity what are the eigenvalues of this matrix?
I'm sure this question is terribly formed, but I'm a physicist, so any suggestions on how to tackle this problem are appreciated.

Comment: The matrix is an infinite circulant (entries depend only on $m-n$). So it is similar to a diagonal matrix by Fourier transformation, i.e. look at $F^{-1}HF$ where $F$ is the discrete Fourier tfm matrix. Hence, if you write $c$ for the top row, find $Fc$. Then take an appropriate continuum limit ...

Comment: Are $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (doubly infinite)?

Comment: @HansEngler yes